# Row filters on a specific field of a row-key

Tags: hbase

I have my row-key made up of 4 components: a,b,c,d
the fields a,b,c,d are computed by applying some hash functions of initial input A,B,C,D.
Finally each component is converted into bytes and padded like so till d.

Now I want to search the particular row let say on the d.
How will I achieve that.

There are Comparators like RegexStringComparator and SubstringComparator, but they ask the input in form of string.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you can look for on their code [here](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator.html) and see that their also convert the given string expr to bytes.